# Validate form fields from InfoPath custom code

Tags: infopath, validation, infopath-forms-services

I'm developing an InfoPath form for **Forms Services**. It has these views:

- **View 1** asks the user to input some basic initial data
- **View 2** calls a web service based on data in View 1 and populates drop-downs accordingly

At the bottom of View 1 I've added a `Next >` button to move to View 2. As part of clicking that button I would like the inputs in View 1 to be validated first. However, there don't appear to be any rules that validate a view or anything in the object model to execute validation rules.

**Is there code that can trigger a field's validation event?**

Comment: Instead of triggering the field's event from code, couldn't you use the OnClick event for the button and then alert or set an error? You could use (I think; haven't tried) Errors.Add (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.infopath.errors.add(VS.80).aspx) for that last part.

Comment: (update) There's an msdn example using JScript here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb229735.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this, at least for InfoPath 2007 (which this question is targeted at), is no. The only solution is to handle all validation manually.